# error: non-static method setListMovie(ArrayList<Movie>) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android

i don't know why there is this error. it want me to add static in my adapter in this code

```
void setListMovie(ArrayList<Movie> listPresident) {
    this.listPresident = listPresident;
}
```

but when i add static in it. 'this' in my code become error. 
this it the my main code that want to add static the adapter class code

```
ListMovieAdapter.setListMovie(list);
```

please help why there is this error and how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your method with `static` key word

```
public static void setListMovie(ArrayList<Movie> newMoviews) {
listPresident = newMoviews;
}
```

and should declare `listPresident` as static variable

Comment: so i have to make it static like this 'private static ArrayList<Movie> listPresident;' ?

Comment: yes because if you are declared variable or functions as static, it's functioning as part of class,not a member of class

Comment: but you have to avoid static variables because they hold memory even you closed app.

Comment: so it must be static?

Comment: Yes @qube, because you can't access non static variables in static method